# how to update a existing report & dashboard in production

Tags: deployment

i have 2015 revenue reports in production,in that same report  i added extra field like 2016 revenue field in sandbox(i also added some records in that existing report). Now i want to show 2016 revenue report in production. How can i do this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use chain sets- reference doc- http://salesforcedeveloperblog.blogspot.in/2011/05/change-set-deployment-steps.html

or Eclipse - reference doc -http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation_for_Eclipse_3.3.x

Comment: i added production once. But i want update it